# How to add two datetime in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

If there's a `dataframe` with two column, how can I add `col[1]` to `col[0]` time only. I mean I have data like behind

```
              stepTime                         Time

0  2019-07-02 00:00:00      2019-08-10 08:52:00

1  2019-07-02 00:00:01      2019-08-10 08:52:00

2  2019-07-02 00:00:02      2019-08-10 08:52:00

3  2019-07-02 00:00:03      2019-08-10 08:52:00

4  2019-07-02 00:00:04      2019-08-10 08:52:00
```

and I want to make new column `realTime` which add `Time` to `stepTime`'s time only like behind

```
              stepTime                      Time              realTime

0  2019-07-02 00:00:00   2019-08-10 08:52:00   2019-08-10 08:52:00

1  2019-07-02 00:00:01   2019-08-10 08:52:00   2019-08-10 08:52:01

2  2019-07-02 00:01:02   2019-08-10 08:52:00   2019-08-10 08:53:02

3  2019-07-02 00:02:03   2019-08-10 08:52:00   2019-08-10 08:54:03

4  2019-07-02 01:05:04   2019-08-10 08:52:00   2019-08-10 09:57:04
```

I tried like this but it's not working

```
df["realTime"] = df.Time + df.stepTime.datetime.strftime('%H')
```

Comment: please format your data correctly it will help to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly add pandas Datetime columns. You must first transform one of the columns in `timedelta` by substracting the date and then add that timedelta to a Datetime:

```
df["realTime"] = df.stepTime + (df.Time - df.Time.dt.floor('D'))
```